# Merge [pre-commit-hook] > [pre-commit] and [svn-administration] > [svnadmin]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

I would like to suggest merging the following tag pairs:

- [pre-commit-hook](/questions/tagged/pre-commit-hook) **>** [pre-commit](/questions/tagged/pre-commit)
- [post-commit-hook](/questions/tagged/post-commit-hook) **>** [post-commit](/questions/tagged/post-commit)
- [svn-administraton](/questions/tagged/svn-administraton) **>** [svnadmin](/questions/tagged/svnadmin)

There are questions tagged with both variants however [pre-commit](/questions/tagged/pre-commit), [post-commit](/questions/tagged/post-commit) and [svnadmin](/questions/tagged/svnadmin) are used more frequently.

One can ask why to merge [svn-administraton](/questions/tagged/svn-administraton) **>** [svnadmin](/questions/tagged/svnadmin). *Note a typo in the tag name BTW!*

The point is that "svn administration" mostly involves `svnadmin` tool and the tasks you perform with `svnadmin` are "svn administration" tasks in any case. :)

**EDIT :**

I suggest that questions about version control hook scripts should be tagged like this:

- If a question is about Hg pre-commit hook it should be tagged [mercurial-hook](/questions/tagged/mercurial-hook), [pre-commit](/questions/tagged/pre-commit),
- If a question is about SVN post-commit hook is should be tagged [svnhooks](/questions/tagged/svnhooks), [post-commit](/questions/tagged/post-commit),
- If a question is about git pre-commit hook it should be tagged [githook](/questions/tagged/githook), [pre-commit](/questions/tagged/pre-commit).

Comment: How would you reconcile these with the [svn-hooks], [mercurial-hook], [githook] and occasional poorly used [hook] tags?

Comment: @Ben If a question is about Hg pre-commit hook it should be tagged [mercurial-hook], [pre-commit] IMHO. In case of SVN the question should be tagged [svnhooks], [pre-commit]. With git it should look like [githook], [pre-commit]. You raise and interesting question that demolishes my mind, actually. xD